# How to change prices per number ordered in WooCommerce

Tags: plugins

Does anyone know a way to make the price of a second item different from the first in WooCommerce? I tried setting up the product so the first item was $245, second is an additional $150.  I used variations and added $150 to each additional variation option.  This works fine if users snag their item from the drop-down menu.  However, if they up the number manually below the drop down or in the cart (using the arrows), it makes every item $245.  Is there a clever way to fix this?  This is visible on: http://cope24.com/shop/cope24-parenting-skill-program/
Thanks!

Comment: This is a woocommerce support question and IMHO not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Not a standard option, there's a plugin for that: [Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/)

Alternatively, you can hide the quantity buttons:

```
div.quantity {
display: none !important;
}
```

or disable it entirely:

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input() {}
```

though both these alternative solutions do this for your entire shop.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my solution was even easier. Since we are only selling via Paypal I don't need ANY cart or additional plugins.  Scrapped the whole lot, built the buttons with my variable prices in the PayPal button maker and pasted them in. Free and easy!